# Midpoint of the shortest distance between 2 rays in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

I would like to come with an algorithm to find the midpoint of the shortest between 2 rays a+t**b** and c+s**d**, where t and s are scalars. I have a scenario which I try to depict like this.[image: closest distance between 2 rays]

One of the strategies I was planning to try was finding out the equation of the plane a(s**b**)c, and project the point t**d** on to abc, and then solve for intersection to get q. Then do the same for p, and then add and divide them by 2 to get r. But, without knowing t and s, I'm wondering whether this is the right way to go. Any help on this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find solution for $s$ and $t$ by

$$ \begin{aligned}
  s & = \frac{(b\cdot d) \left( (a \cdot d)-(b \cdot c) \right)-(a \cdot d)(c \cdot d)}{(b \cdot d)^2-1} \\
  t & = \frac{(b\cdot d) \left( (c \cdot d)-(a \cdot d) \right)-(b \cdot c)(a \cdot b)}{(b \cdot d)^2-1} \\
\end{aligned} $$

where ${\cdot}$ is the dot product.

The mid point is then $r=\frac{1}{2} ( a+c+b t+d s)$

**HOW ?**

Point $p$ is closest point on line $c+sd$ to point $q$, and point $q$ is closest on line $a+b t$ to $p$.

The above leads to $$a+b t = c+ d s + \frac{(a \times b)\times b}{b \cdot b} $$ and  $$c+ d s = a+b t + \frac{(c \times d)\times d}{d \cdot d} $$

I can dispose the cross products by projecting along $b$ and $d$

$$ b \cdot (a+b t) = b \cdot (c+d s) + 0 $$
$$ d \cdot (c+d s) = d \cdot (a+b t) + 0 $$

This is two *scalar* equations solvable for $t$ and $s$.

Comment: This is a nice method. But a couple of point I don't understand. What the expression, (a x b) x b / b.b gives me (probably the vector pq, but how?). I get how you project and equate that to zero, but it might be nice if there's a small explanation there too.

Comment: The vector from $a$ to $p$ projected onto the line is $b\left(\frac{b\cdot (p-a)}{b\cdot b}\right)$ and the above is another way of doing projections using the vector triple cross product.

Comment: @ja72 I'm trying to implement this, but I'm getting different results depending on the sizes of b and d (even though they would represent the same rays). Do these vectors have to be normalized or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4):

One way to approach this is:

Let $r_{1o}$ and $r_{1d}$ define the origin and direction of the first ray.

Let $r_{2o}$ and $r_{2d}$ define the origin and direction of the second ray.

Minimise $d = ((r_{1o} + {r_{1d}}t) - p)^2$ where $p$ is a point on $r_2$.

$$d = ((r_{1o} + {r_{1d}}t) - p)^2$$
$$=(r_{1d}t + (r_{1o} - p))^2$$
$$=r_{1d}.r_{1d}t^2 + 2(r_{1o} - p).r_{1d}t + (r_{1o} - p)^2$$

$$dd/dt = 2r_{1d}.r_{1d}t + 2(r_{1o} - p).r_{1d}$$

Then Let $dd/dt = 0$

$$0 = 2r_{1d}.r_{1d}t + 2(r_{1o} - p).r_{1d}$$
$$0 = r_{1d}.r_{1d}t + (r_{1o} - p).r_{1d}$$

and then substitute $p$ with $r_{2o} + r_{2d}s$

Giving:

$$0 = r_{1d}.r_{1d}t + (r_{1o} - r_{2o} - r_{2d}s).r_{1d}$$
$$0 = r_{1d}.r_{1d}t - r_{2d}.r_{1d}s + (r_{1o} - r_{2o}).r_{1d}$$
$$r_{1d}.r_{1d}t - r_{2d}.r_{1d}s = -(r_{1o} - r_{2o}).r_{1d}$$

Now exchange $r_{1*}$ with $r_{2*}$, and $s$ with $t$ to simulate going through the same process with the other ray yielding:

$$r_{2d}.r_{2d}s - r_{1d}.r_{2d}t = -(r_{2o} - r_{1o}).r_{2d}$$
$$-r_{1d}.r_{2d}t + r_{2d}.r_{2d}s = -(r_{2o} - r_{1o}).r_{2d}$$

And now you have two simultaneous equations to solve:

$$r_{1d}.r_{1d}t - r_{2d}.r_{1d}s = -(r_{1o} - r_{2o}).r_{1d}$$
$$-r_{1d}.r_{2d}t + r_{2d}.r_{2d}s = -(r_{2o} - r_{1o}).r_{2d}$$

Giving:

$$t = \frac{-((r_{1o} - r_{2o}).r_{1d})(r_{2d}.r_{2d}) - (r_{2d}.r_{1d})((r_{2o} - r_{1o}).r_{2d})}{(r_{1d}.r_{1d})(r_{2d}.r_{2d}) - (r_{2d}.r_{1d})(r_{1d}.r_{2d})}$$
$$s = \frac{-(r_{1d}.r_{1d})((r_{2o} - r_{1o}).r_{2d}) - ((r_{1o} - r_{2o}).r_{1d})(r_{1d}.r_{2d})}{(r_{1d}.r_{1d})(r_{2d}.r_{2d}) - (r_{2d}.r_{1d})(r_{1d}.r_{2d})}$$

Above solved with Cramer's rule because I was getting lazy.

This can be rearranged to make the common sub-expressions more visible (for implementation with temporary variables)

$$t = \frac{((r_{2o} - r_{1o}).r_{1d})(r_{2d}.r_{2d}) + ((r_{1o} - r_{2o}).r_{2d})(r_{1d}.r_{2d})}{(r_{1d}.r_{1d})(r_{2d}.r_{2d}) - (r_{1d}.r_{2d})^2}$$
$$s = \frac{((r_{1o} - r_{2o}).r_{2d})(r_{1d}.r_{1d}) + ((r_{2o} - r_{1o}).r_{1d})(r_{1d}.r_{2d})}{(r_{1d}.r_{1d})(r_{2d}.r_{2d}) - (r_{1d}.r_{2d})^2}$$

Then taking the average for the mid point: $$m = \frac{(r_{1o} + r_{1d}t) + (r_{2o} + r_{2d}s)}{2}$$

This formula should work for non-normalized direction vectors.

Comment: This actually works. I got strange results with the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer works too. But it assumes unit direction vectors (needs to be normalized). If you simplified mine above for using unit vectors, then it will collapse to the same formula as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the cross product $\vec b \times \vec d$. It will be perpendicular to both lines.

EDIT: other more efficient hint... You have your midpoint $R$.

Distance between $R$ and first line is $d_1=\dfrac{\mid \mid\vec{RA}\times \vec b\mid \mid}{\mid\mid\vec b \mid\mid}$

Do the same with the other line and say that they are equal...

Comment: I'm trying to get a solution based on your most efficient hint, but say r = ai + bj + ck, I get a single equation with squares of a, b and c. Since this is not a vector anymore I can't get 3 equations out of this, I believe (or am I wrong?). Could you expand on your hint?

Comment: @dev_nut Well, there is another condition, that is that your point $R$ is the minimum point for which it is true.